# Custom seeder in laravel 5.4

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-seeding

how can we make custom seeder in **Laravel** which can read the folder name and put into a specific column in database and the sub folder's name in the next column and finally the file name in the last?

Comment: See docs properly

Answer (score 1):

Create seeder by artisan command for Users table below command run

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder
```

Now in database folder find UserTableSeeder.php in this

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => str_random(10),
            'email' => str_random(10).'@gmail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

in this str_random for random string generate
Now, run this seeder by below command

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Comment: thanks but i knew this. i am building an application where a huge data is to be seeded into the database where the names of the main folders are the cities and the sub folders are the companies and files are the office locations. So i need a seeder which can read the name of the main folders are put it the cites column in the database and so on.

Answer (score 0):

check the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding#writing-seeders.